# Override index array from API result

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux, state

Having a problem overriding the index of array in redux state :/

I am receiving a data from an endpoint and the results are:

e.g.

```
data: 
 [{
    0: {id: 123, name: test1 },
    1: {id: 456, name: test2 },
    3: {id: 789, name: test3 },
 }]
```

But I want to change the index of the array based on the result object.

```
data:
 [{
    123: {id: 123, name: test1 },
    456: {id: 456, name: test2 },
    789: {id: 789, name: test3 },
 }]
```

Then save these to reducer.

This is the exact data that returned from an endpoint.
[image]

I have tried

```
let data = action.payload.data.map(item => {
    return {
        [item.id]: item
    }
})
```

and got the result of

```
[
0: {123: {id: 123, name: 'test1'}},
1: {456: {id: 456, name: 'test2'}}
]
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

A combination of [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) and [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) must do the trick:

```js
const data = [{

0: {id: 123, name: "test1" },

1: {id: 456, name: "test2" },

3: {id: 789, name: "test3" },

}];

const output = data.map(obj => Object.values(obj).reduce((acc, a) => ({ ...acc, [a.id]: a }), {}));

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` and `Object.entries` and `Object.fromEntries`

```js
let data = [{0: { id: 123,name: 'test1'},1: {id: 456,name: 'test2'}, 3: {id: 789,name: 'test3'},}]

let op = data.map(val => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(val).map(([key, value]) => [value.id, value])))

console.log(op)
```

Or you can use `map` and `Object.values` and `reduce`

```js
let data = [{0: { id: 123,name: 'test1'},1: {id: 456,name: 'test2'}, 3: {id: 789,name: 'test3'},}]

let op = data.map(val=> {
  let values = Object.values(val)
  let obj = values.reduce((op, inp) => {
    op[inp.id] = inp
    return op
  },{})
  return obj  
})

console.log(op)
```

Comment: Thanks man, but seems not working, BTW the ID is a string and this is the data returned:



data = [
    {fixtureId: 123,name: 'test1'},
    {fixtureId: 456,name: 'test2'}, 
    {fixtureId: 789,name: 'test3'}
 ]

Comment: @siney71 what is not working can you explain the problem you're facing ? the answer is in accordance to the data you posted in question, since here key is changed so you need to used `fixtureId` instead of `id`,  you can update question with the code you've tried